# how to play m4s chunks downloaded from mpd file

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, mpeg-dash

Below i have written sample code to download first 7 chunks of mpd file of single quality alongwith base url mp4 of that particular quality.I am putting m4s chunks in queue of strings.How can i play the downloaded data.
i have queue in which at first iteration is mp4 segment of particular quality
and then in subsequent iterations i have m4s chunks of same quality
Now i want to play this queue buffer using ffmpeg or gstreamer.How can i do this
Individually i am able to play by downloading single mp4(of particular quality in mpd structure) then using cat concatenating with m4s chunks and then play.

In open source libdash how it is done,if anyone has any idea.

Please guide.

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h> 
#include <queue>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
string data; 
std::queue<string> myqueue;
int size =0;



 size_t writeCallback(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* up)
 { 

  printf("size  = %d\n\n\n",size);
  printf("size nmemb  = %d\n\n\n\n\n",nmemb);
  for (int c = 0; c<size*nmemb; c++)
  {
    data.push_back(buf[c]);
  }

  myqueue.push (data);  
   return size*nmemb; //tell curl how many bytes we handled
  }



  int main()
  {
  CURL* curl; //our curl object
  char url_firstpart[80];// = NULL;
  char bitwide_chunk[10];
  char buffer[10];


curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL); //pretty obvious
curl = curl_easy_init();

for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
{   

strcpy(url_firstpart,"http://www-itec.uni- klu.ac.at/ftp/datasets/mmsys12/Valkaama/valkaama_1s/valkaama_1s_50kbit/valkaama_1s");
string str = to_string(i);

char * writable = new char[str.size() + 1];
std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), writable);
writable[str.size()] = '\0'; 

strcat(writable,".m4s"); 
printf("concanated chink is %s\n",writable);

strcat(url_firstpart,bitwide_chunk);
puts(url_firstpart);


curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,url_firstpart);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &writeCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L); 

curl_easy_perform(curl);



}

size = myqueue.size();
printf("Final size of queue = %d\n",size);
cout << endl << data << endl;
  cin.get();

  curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  curl_global_cleanup();

  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I think you should make more clear what you need. At first it seems like it is DASH question but your past this point. It's now a pure gstreamer/ffmpeg question: How to attach a datasource consisting from multiple files/datasource?

Comment: i think the question is how to play file using buffer in gstreamer e.g instead of giving file in uri i should give buffer to play the file.